# Set spark conf for databricks cluster in python init script

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Maybe is trivial but i didn't found any solutions for this, I would like to set specific azure credentials for each databricks cluster.
This goes with executing the following python code in a notebook:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get('<secrets-scope>', '<Service-principal-ID-var>'))
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get('<secrets-scope>', '<Service-principal-Secret-var>'))
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<endpoint>")
```

The basic idea for setting the credentials for each cluster is to create a cluster scoped init script (for each cluster) that execute the previous lines of code.

Is this possibile somehow?

**EDIT**

I've already find out and tested that this conf could be set directly in the cluster advanced options. Anyway I would prefer not to left any secret hardcoded here.

Here an example for reference:

[image: spark conf in advanced options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would prefer not to left any secret hardcoded here.

You can use **Databricks secret scope** in the Spark config by specifying them in  `{{}}`.

For whatever secrets you don't want to hard code, create Azure Key vault secret and Databrick secret scope for all.

**My sample:**

[image]

**Secret scope:**

[image]

For sample I have used the below secret.

[image]

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/tutorials/run-jobs-with-service-principals#--create-a-job-in-azure-databricks-and-configure-the-cluster-to-read-secrets-from-the-secret-scope), specify the secret like `{{secrets/<secret-scope-name>/<secret-name>}}`. Follow the below code example from the same **Documentation**.

```
fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net <application-id>
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/<secret-scope-name>/<secret-name>}}
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your response. Your solution seems perfect to me, but I can't understand how databricks authenticate to the AKV. Wich credentials does it use to access the AKV? Does it impersonate the user? and when the cluster is called in "headless" mode, e.g. from an ADF scheduled pipeline it will use ADF "credentials" (e.g. the managed identity) to authenticate to the AKV and retrieve the secrets?

Comment: while creating the secret scope, it will ask the AKV details like above. It uses those to get the secret as mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/tutorials/run-jobs-with-service-principals#--step-2-create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope). **AFAIK**, when we use ADF scheduled pipeline, if we use existing cluster then it will use these secrets. If we use new cluster I think we should use the same syntax in the spark config which also uses same secrets.